# Can't create repo

Tags: artifactory

I'm running Artifactory Pro 5.4.3 using docker which is behind haproxy (in mesos) which is fronted by an ELB. Whenever I try to create a new repo (doesn't matter what kind) I get 405's and 500's in my `request.log`:

```
20170706025422|17|REQUEST|172.16.1.138|james|GET|/ui/admin/repositories/defaultvalues|HTTP/1.1|500|0
20170706025430|2|REQUEST|172.16.1.138|james|POST|/ui/admin/repositories/discoversmartrepocapabilities|HTTP/1.1|400|274
20170706025430|1|REQUEST|172.16.1.138|james|POST|/ui/admin/repositories/testremote|HTTP/1.1|400|274
```

I also get a stack trace in my `artifactory.log`:

```
2017-07-06 02:54:22,365 [http-nio-8081-exec-6] [ERROR] (o.a.r.c.e.GlobalExceptionMapper:48) - String index out of range: -4
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -4
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.service.admin.configuration.repositories.util.GetDefaultRepositoryValues.lambda$2(GetDefaultRepositoryValues.java:82) ~[artifactory-rest-ui-5.4.3.jar:na]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.service.admin.configuration.repositories.util.GetDefaultRepositoryValues.populateRemoteNetworkWithCertificates(GetDefaultRepositoryValues.java:83) ~[artifactory-rest-ui-5.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.service.admin.configuration.repositories.util.GetDefaultRepositoryValues.execute(GetDefaultRepositoryValues.java:71) ~[artifactory-rest-ui-5.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.service.ServiceExecutor.process(ServiceExecutor.java:38) ~[artifactory-rest-common-5.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.resource.BaseResource.runService(BaseResource.java:127) ~[artifactory-rest-common-5.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.resource.admin.configuration.repositories.RepoConfigResource.getRepoConfigDefaultValues(RepoConfigResource.java:88) ~[artifactory-rest-ui-5.4.3.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor421.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.execute(RepoFilter.java:185) [artifactory-web-application-5.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doFilter(RepoFilter.java:94) [artifactory-web-application-5.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.useAuthentication(AccessFilter.java:399) [artifactory-web-application-5.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessFilter.java:211) [artifactory-web-application-5.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:165) [artifactory-web-application-5.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:67) [artifactory-web-application-5.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164) [spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80) [spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:62) [artifactory-web-application-5.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryFilter.java:116) [artifactory-web-application-5.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1524) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1480) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.41]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
```

I'm not sure what to do at this point. It's pretty annoying. I used to be able to create repos but haven't in a while.

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://forums.jfrog.org/Mirror-any-issue-what-am-I-doing-wrong-td7578065.html

Comment: First - this looks like a bug - you should contact JFrog Support and report it.  
Second - It looks like you have an entry in your Artifactory keystore with an alias shorter than 11 characters. Once you remove this entry or rename its alias, this issue should be solved (Go to Admin > Security > Signing Keys).